# Whitelisted keys when benchmarking extrinsic calls

Tags: pallet, weight, benchmarking, frame, benchmark

There are a few storage keys that are always whitelisted before each benchmarking pallet extrinsic call (`:transaction_level`, `:extrinsic_index`, and `:intrablock_entropy`), apart from the whitelisted keys that can be added.

1. Is `#[extrinsic_call]` isolated when the benchmarking test is executed or is it plugged in `with_transaction`? This might be related to the `:transaction_level` whitelisting.
2. How do `:extrinsic_index`, and `:intrablock_entropy` affect the extrinsic call weight? Are they used whenever you benchmark hooks such as `on_finalize`?
3. When you benchmark a signed extrinsic call, why is the caller always whitelisted? Is the read/write weight of the caller included whenever you benchmark the base block weight?